# Matching everything except a specified regex

Tags: regex, .net-4.0

I have a huge file, and I want to blow away everything in the file except for what matches my regex. I know I can get matches and just extract those, but I want to keep my file and get rid of everything else.

Here's my regex:

```
"Id":\d+
```

How do I say "Match everything **except** `"Id":\d+`". Something along the lines of

`!("Id":\d+) (pseudo regex)` ?

I want to use it with a Regex Replace function. In english I want to say:

> Get all text that isn't `"Id":\d+` and replace it with and empty string.

Comment: When you say throw away everything else, do you mean keep lines containing the regex or just keep the strings which match the regex?

Comment: Are you saying you want a regex that matches everything except what your regex matches?

Comment: your question sounds like a logical mind trap. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
string path = @"c:\temp.txt"; // your file here
string pattern = @".*?(Id:\d+\s?).*?|.+";
Regex rx = new Regex(pattern);

var lines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
using (var writer = File.CreateText(path))
{
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        string result = rx.Replace(line, "$1");
        if (result == "")
            continue;

        writer.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

The pattern will preserve spaces between multiple *Id:Number* occurrences on the same line. If you only have one `Id` per line you can remove the `\s?` from the pattern. `File.CreateText` will open and overwrite your existing file. If a replacement results in an empty string it will be skipped over. Otherwise the result will be written to the file.

The first part of the pattern matches *Id:Number* occurrences. It includes an alternation for `.+` to match lines where *Id:Number* does not appear. The replacement uses `$1` to replace the match with the contents of the first group, which is the actual `Id` part: `(Id:\d+\s?)`.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but I totally don't get what your problem is. Shouldn't it be easy to grep the matches into a new file?

Yoo wrote:

> Get all text that isn't "Id":\d+ and replace it with and empty string.

A logical equivalent would be:

> Get all text that matches `"Id":\d+` and place it in a new file. Replace the old file with the new one.

Comment: Micah mentions in his question that he doesn't want to do that

Comment: But he said "I want to blow away everything in the file except for what matches my regex", so I understand it as he wants all lines that match his regex. I find it a little bit confusing.

Answer (score 1):

well, the opposite of `\d` is `\D` in perl-ish regexes.  Does .net have something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I haven't use .net before, but following works in java

```
System.out.println("abcd Id:12351abcdf".replaceAll(".*(Id:\\d+).*","$1"));
```

produces output

```
Id:12351
```

Although in true sense it doesnt match the criteria of matching everything except Id:\d+, but it does the job

Comment: Try and see what happens when you have two occurrences of `Id:234` in your string...